# Boxplots don't show in plot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data.frame (data) with 1000 rows and 3 columns. I used the `melt` function to create this so, the column `type` is the id and the other two are the `variable` and the `vlaue`. I want to create boxplots and I used the command :

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I don't see any error but the result does not show the boxplots.

example of the dataframe:

```
type variable value

M1       ML2    -2
M1       ML5    -10
M1       ML10   -5
M1       ML8    -1
M1       ML3    -5
M1       ML9    -12
M1       ML4    -3
```

result: [image]

How can I have the boxplots? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried using the baseR `boxplot` function?

Comment: I tried boxplot(data$variable ~ adata$value, data =data,main = "title",ylab = "X",xlab = "Y") but I get the error Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object

Comment: how many `value`;s do you have for each `variable`?

Comment: ie if you only have one value for each variable how can a box (that show summary stats of the distribution) be shown. Example, `dat <- data.frame(variable=letters[1:5], value=rnorm(5)) ; ggplot(dat,aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: some variables are the same type so for each variable I have approximately 3 values.

Comment: perhaps there is very little variation between the values , or perhaps there is large spread in the y-values so that the distribution cannot be plot Otherwise, I think  a small reproducible example is needed [ps another example: `dat <-  data.frame(variable=rep(letters[1:5],each=3) ,
                 value=c(rnorm(9), rnorm(3, 100), rnorm(3,500)))`

Comment: @user20650 The variation between the values is very little, but I didn't know that this would give these results. I will check it.